Tikz Drawing: Coordinate System with Origin on Curve
I'd like to draw the following sketch:

How can I do that? I struggle with the coordinate axes.
My code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
    \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
    \draw (D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=5];
    \filldraw[black] (3.57,-1.5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{Origin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, done!

Where do you need the coordinate system? At a specific distance a long the path? At a specific angle? At a specific point?

Adaptations

set origin as coordinate (O) using [pos=0.5] instead of magic numbers
draw arrows relative to origin with (O) -- ++(135:2) etc.
draw right angle symbol by shifting an arc from the origin

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
    \draw (D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=5] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);
    \filldraw[black] (O) circle (2pt) node [below right] {Origin};
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(135:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(45:2);
    \draw ([shift=(45:.4)] O) arc (45:135:.4);
    \filldraw ([shift=(90:.2)] O) circle (.4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result


The spath3 TikZ library has the capability to set the transformation so that the origin is at a specific point on a curve, and so that the x-axis is tangential to that curve.
The following code illustrates this. It also shows how to use a point on a curve as a coordinate without the wider transformation.
There is one subtlety about how the point on the curve is specified, which is detailed in the documentation. It isn't by arc length, but by parametrisation of individual drawing components of the curve (ie line segments, and bezier curves). So if the curve has two components then the interval [0,.5] maps to the parametrisation of the first component, while [.5,1] to the second.
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/727961/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  arrows.meta
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95,>=Latex]
\coordinate (D) at (0,0);
\draw[spath/save=curve] (D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=5];
\filldraw[black] (spath cs:curve .5) circle[radius=2pt] node[anchor=east]{Origin};
\begin{scope}[spath/transform to={curve}{.5}]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Another solution is to use \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} as follows. Not necessarily the best answer, but this is how I usually do this sort of thing.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newcommand{\Vt}{0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
decoration={markings,
mark=at position \Vt with {\fill (0,0) coordinate (DeliberatelyLongName0) circle[radius=0.062];},
mark=at position \Vt with {\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName1);},
mark=at position \Vt with {\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName2);},
},
postaction={decorate}
]%%% END
(0,0) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=5];
\draw pic[draw,-,angle eccentricity=1.4, angle radius=0.3cm]{right angle=DeliberatelyLongName1--DeliberatelyLongName0--DeliberatelyLongName2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Based upon the answer by dexteritas, I created a more flexible approach which should work for any point at/shape of the curve.
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, angles, calc}

\newcommand{\pathCoordinateCreator}[1]{
    coordinate [pos=#1] (O) coordinate [pos=#1-0.01] (OO)
}

\newcommand{\coordinateSystem}[1][black]{
    \path[draw=#1, fill=#1] (O) circle (2pt) coordinate(originMarker);
    \path(OO)--(O)[draw=#1, ->, >=stealth']{--([turn]180:2)} coordinate (A);
    \path(OO)--(O)[draw=#1, ->, >=stealth']{--([turn]-90:2)} coordinate (B);
    \path pic [draw=#1, angle eccentricity=.5, pic text=\textcolor{#1}{\textbf{.}}]
    {angle = A--O--B};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
        \draw[save path=\curve] (D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=5]\pathCoordinateCreator{0.5};

        \coordinateSystem
        \node[below right] at (originMarker){Origin};
        
        % DESCRIPTION: Just for showcasing the flexibility and limitations of approach
        \foreach \offset/\axiscolor in {{0.2}/{red}, {0.875}/{cyan}}{
            \path (D) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=5]\pathCoordinateCreator{\offset};
            \coordinateSystem[\axiscolor]
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This results in the following:

The trick behind this approach is to use the tangent coordinate system of TikZ: By selecting two points (OO) and (O) very close to each other, one can access the tangent information by first drawing a short "dummy" segment (OO)--(O), which stores the required tangent information, which in turn can be accessed via the --([turn]<ANGLE>:<RADIUS>) syntax. In combination with the angles syntax, this allows to place the coordinate system anywhere on the curve (as demonstrated with the \foreach) and still maintain the correct orientation without complicated manual adjustments each time.
The limitation of this approach is that one cannot store the path information data: This requires to "redraw" the path each time you want to add a coordinate system at another position. In this case, the spath3 approach by Andrew Stacey and markings approach by Jasper are better, since they do not have this problem.
Remarks:
After some more detailed testing, I realized the following:

This approach does not work in conjunction with the to syntax
It cannot handle curves consisting of multiple parts


There are a lot of answers but no overview (and a pic solution is missing).

So, you want to draw something in relation to direction of a point on a path.
PGF/TikZ provides – as always – plenty of ways to achieve this.
In the following examples, the “coordinate system” consists of an x (blue) and y (green) axis in the xyz coordinate system, a circle at the origin in the canvas coordinate system and a angle pic between the axes at said origin. Roughly, this is:
\draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y) |- coordinate (O) (right:1)
                                              coordinate (x);
\fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
\pic[angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=x--O--y};


Of course, you can always just figure out the needed rotation for yourself.
Mathematically, for a circular arc, this is relatively easy:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3];
\begin{scope}[thick, shift={(3,5)}, shift=(180:-3), shift=(135:3), rotate=45]
  \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y) |- coordinate (O) (right:1)
                                                coordinate (x);
  \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
  \pic[angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=x--O--y};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

But this is no fun!

For many path operations, “timers” are implemented that map the values
between 0 and 1 to the points along the path operation.
The manual calls this placing nodes on lines and curves explicitly or
implicitly. (Read that and look at the examples.)
This not also applies to nodes (and coordinates) but also to pics.
This means, you can place any drawing along a path operation.
With sloped and allow upside down active,
the canvas coordinate system's x axis will point in the direction
of the path operation and the y axis points orthogonally to the left.
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pics/CSys/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code={
      \tikzset{every path/.append style=thick}
      \path[CSys y-CSys x, pic actions, path only, draw] (up:1) coordinate (-y)
                                   |- coordinate (-O) (right:1) coordinate (-x);
      \path[pic actions, path only, fill]
        (-O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
      \pic[-, angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.]
        {angle=\tikzpicname-x--\tikzpicname-O--\tikzpicname-y};
    }
  }
]
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3]
                pic[midway] (CS) {CSys};
\end{tikzpicture}

Here, midway stands for pos = 0.5, i.e. halfway along the arc.
I like this solution syntactically because it is relatively short
but very flexible.
With the edge node key, pics can also be added as part of a style
(for a to or edge operation).
Disadvantages:

only applicable to path operations that have timers
(though, the most important ones do have timers)
this uses timers that are not necessarily linear to the distance traveled,
precise placements may not be easily achieved
due to #1363, this needs \tikzpicname for the pic nested inside
due to #1058, sloped doesn't like global transformation,
a fix exists, though


The decoration.markings library offers a very similar functionality
which however works very differently.
Instead of a time along a path operation, a distance
or a fraction of the total distance along the decorated path
or path segment is used to find the appropriate poin along a path
and its vector.
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  CSys/.style args={#1:#2}{
    decoration={
      name=markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {
        \tikzset{name prefix={#2-}, every path/.append style=thick}
        \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y)
        |- coordinate (O) (right:1) coordinate (x);
        \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
        \pic[-, angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=#2-x--#2-O--#2-y};
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  }
]
\draw[->, CSys=.5:CS] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}

This allows to place drawings along paths that are not available by timers,
including shapes' paths.
Placing drawings in relation to the distance travelled is certainly a helpful
functionality but with global transformation active,
this position doesn't transform the same.
Disadvantages:

I don't like the syntax
uses untransformed distance instead of a time
not easy to add to a to path operation via a style


I provide a save transformation key as well as a pic
that saves the current transformation for later use
(→ load transformation).
This doesn't provide a new functionality to find a point along a path
but allows it to find it first and use it later:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3]
  pic[midway] (CS) {save transformation};
\begin{scope}[thick, load transformation=CS]
  \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y)
  |- coordinate (O) (right:1) coordinate (x);
  \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
  \pic[angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=x--O--y};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

This can be used with any other solution but I'll show it here with a pic
along the arc.

The turn key can be used to access coordinate in a coordinate system
tangential to the previous path segment.
It can be used here but is too annoying to be helpful, in my opinion.

If you want to place a drawing along a path at a specific point or at a specific x or y value, we can use the intersections library to find that point along the path. The spath3 library can then be used to access these points so that any of the solutions 2., 3. or 4. can be used.


Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles}
\tikzset{
  CSys/.tip=Straight Barb,
  CSys x/.tip=CSys[blue!50],
  CSys y/.tip=CSys[green]}
\newcommand*\tikzpicname{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/name prefix}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  save transformation/.code=%
    \pgfgettransform\tikz@temp
    \global\expandafter\let\csname tikz@transform@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\tikz@temp,
  pics/save transformation/.default=,
  pics/save transformation/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down, foreground code=, code=, background code=,
    setup code=\tikzset{save transformation={#1}}},
  load transformation/.code=%
    \ifcsname tikz@transform@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname
      \expandafter\pgfsettransform\csname tikz@transform@\tikz@pp@name{#1}\endcsname
    \else\ifcsname tikz@transform@#1\endcsname
      \expandafter\pgfsettransform\csname tikz@transform@#1\endcsname
    \else
      \tikz@error{No saved transformation named '\tikz@pp@name{#1}' or '#1' found.}%
    \fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3];
\begin{scope}[thick, shift={(3,5)}, shift=(180:-3), shift=(135:3), rotate=45]
  \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y) |- coordinate (O) (right:1)
                                                coordinate (x);
  \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
  \pic[angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=x--O--y};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pics/CSys/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code={
      \tikzset{every path/.append style=thick}
      \path[CSys y-CSys x, pic actions, path only, draw] (up:1) coordinate (-y)
                                   |- coordinate (-O) (right:1) coordinate (-x);
      \path[pic actions, path only, fill]
        (-O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
      \pic[-, angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.]
        {angle=\tikzpicname-x--\tikzpicname-O--\tikzpicname-y};
    }
  }
]
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3]
                pic[midway] (CS) {CSys};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  CSys/.style args={#1:#2}{
    decoration={
      name=markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {
        \tikzset{name prefix={#2-}, every path/.append style=thick}
        \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y)
        |- coordinate (O) (right:1) coordinate (x);
        \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
        \pic[-, angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=#2-x--#2-O--#2-y};
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  }
]
\draw[->, CSys=.5:CS] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (3,5) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-90, radius=3]
  pic[midway] (CS) {save transformation};
\begin{scope}[thick, load transformation=CS]
  \draw[CSys y-CSys x] (up:1) coordinate (y)
  |- coordinate (O) (right:1) coordinate (x);
  \fill (O) circle[radius=1.5pt] node[right=2pt] {Origin};
  \pic[angle radius=10pt, draw, pic text=.] {angle=x--O--y};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

